# How to run Scala compiled classes from a different directory

Tags: scala, batch-file

Under Windows, I can run a Scala script from a different directory using a batch script like:

Hello.bat:

```
@scala "%~dp0Hello.scala" %*
```

(%~dp0 will be translated to the path where the batch file is)

So I can call it like this:

```
c:\somedir>path\to\scala\script\Hello
Hello World!
c:\somedir>path\to\scala\script\Hello Moon
Hello Moon!
```

Or, if the directory where the script is is already in the path, I could simply use:

```
c:\somedir>Hello
Hello World!
c:\somedir>Hello Moon
Hello Moon!
```

I can't do the same thing for compiled classes:

```
@scala "%~dp0Hello.class" %*
```

won't work, and

```
@scala -howtorun:object "%~dp0Hello.class" %*
```

wont't work either, as well as

```
@scala -howtorun:object "%~dp0Hello" %*
```

This one:

```
@scala -howtorun:object "Hello" %*
```

only works if I am at the same directory, same as:

```
@scala Hello %*
```

And:

```
@cd %~dp0
@scala Hello %*
```

works, but it exits in the directory of the script, not where I was when I called it!

How can I tell scala where to find a class that I am trying to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Let me know if I've misunderstood your question, as I suspect you know this already ... )

Classes to be executed must be on the classpath. Simply put you can either:

```
set CLASSPATH=/path/to/where/your/base/package/is;%CLASSPATH%
```

or you can put it explicitly in your scala invocation

```
scala -classpath /path/to/where/your/base/package/is;%CLASSPATH%
```

Comment: My apologies. The flag should be -classpath, not -cp. Also the path separator is ';', not ':'.  Edited. :)

Comment: both -cp and -classpath were accepted, but either way I got this error:
__'-classpath' does not accept multiple arguments__
(but I was passing one argument only)

Comment: @Grignoli The most probable reason for the error message is that there are spaces inside `CLASSPATH`. You could try putting double quotes around the the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just for documentation purposes:

Thanks to Synesso's answer I was able to achieve it with this:

```
@echo off
set CLASSPATH_tmp=%CLASSPATH%
set CLASSPATH=%~dp0;%CLASSPATH%
call scala Hello %*
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH_tmp%
set CLASSPATH_tmp=
```

the -cp modifier was not accepted by scala (under Windows), so this bat file adds the application directory to the CLASSPATH environment variable temporarily.